# Emulate nginx proxy configuration in apache with mod_proxy, how to?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, proxy

I have a working configuration in nginx which is like this

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_redirect default;

        proxy_set_header    Host        $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        client_max_body_size       100m;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout      600;
        proxy_send_timeout         600;
        proxy_read_timeout         600;

        proxy_buffer_size          4k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    }

    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|htm|html)$ {
        root PATH_TO_STATIC_CONTENT;
    }
```

}

How can I emulate this with apache ? I tried the below configuration but the static content do not serve.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot PATH_TO_STATIC CONTENT
<Location />
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8000
</Location>
<LocationMatch SAME_REGEXP_AS_NGINX>
    ProxyPass !
</LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I get static content to serve in the same way as nginx does? Or is it even possible ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The order of `ProxyPass` directives matters, and unlike nginx, all location blocks that are match are applied, from least specific to most specific.

In other words, you'll need to change your approach a bit for it to work.

Probably the more straightforward and readable approach would be to use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|htm|html)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8000/$1 [P,L]
```